# Search query over multiple REST resources

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, spring-data-rest, hateoas

**TLDR: need standard/framework to accomplish such a query `/courses?teacher.age=30` over multiple resources (course, teacher).**

We are using Spring Data Rest to expose our relational database tables in a hateoas format. The entities are published as REST resources.

Now, the users would like to search over multiple resources.
For example *"give me the names of all courses given by a teacher of 30 years old"*.

Because we need courses, this would be a search operation on `/courses`.
However, the age of a teacher is on `/teachers`.
So in 2 steps:
`/teachers?age=30` which have `_links` to courses. Then, every course can be opened to inspect it's name (eg: `/course/942`).

A more intuitive operation would be to directly call `/courses?teacher.age=30`. 
This is what we would like to accomplish.

Of course, we can implement this by hand. But the real question is: are there already existing standards (and popular libraries) to accomplish this? 
We would like to find a scalable solution, where not every attribute (to search on) has to be added manually.
This dot-notation is just a way of representing the query. It is not a requirement of a standard/library.

Characteristics of our application:

- relational database (postgres)
- json api
- hal/hateoas

Comment: Doesn't Spring Data Rest's QueryDsl extension do exactly what you need? https://spring.io/blog/2015/09/04/what-s-new-in-spring-data-release-gosling#querydsl-support

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43608765/use-spring-boot-internal-controllers-with-requestparam-to-provide-search-metho/43610955#43610955

Comment: @AlanHay Yes, you're right. In the mean-time I found this out myself. I'm still missing clear documentation about the mapping between url query parameters and the java dsl queries.